# How to deal with large amount of XML data in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlperformance, sqlxml

In a table there are 10 columns and 2 of those columns store huge amounts of data. One column (`XML` datatype) stores XML data, another column (`NVARCHAR(MAX)`) stores JSON data. Each rows size around 1.4 MB. Moreover, when I am using a `SELECT` command it takes a lot of time (22 seconds) to load only one record

```
TABLE - [dbo].[CampaignConfiguration](
[CampaignId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ConfigurationXml] [xml] NOT NULL,
[ConfigurationRules] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[RulesVersion] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CampaignCalculationParameters] [nvarchar](max) NULL 


Select * 
From CampaignConfiguration
Where campaignid = 'EB5C2CDB-C076-5174-61D1-D9EA0E04975A';
```

Is there any better way to deal with to improve `SELECT` query performance?

Comment: If you really **need** those columns - then no, that's just the time it takes to load that data. If you **DON'T** need those columns - use an appropriate `SELECT (list-of-columns)` to **avoid** loading those huge columns, and load only those (other) columns that you **really need** (that's a recommended Best Practice anyways - avoid `SELECT *` in production code)

Comment: @marc_s we need these columns data to process some business logic. Problem is, it is slows down when trying to fetch records. Or we need to store those data as external XML and JSON file instead of store in Database

Comment: Can you show us a bit more details? What's the table structure (what columns, what datatypes)? Do you have any indexes on that table - if so, what do they look like? Is the time really spent on fetching the data? Have you checked the actual execution plan of the query? Does that show any anomalies?